# I²C between ATTiny85 (8MHz) and Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, attiny

I keep receiving the following error in myATTiny85-Slave code below:

> sketch_mar12a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
>
> sketch_mar12a:19: error: 'class USI_TWI_S' has no member named 'onRequest'

I have downloaded **[TinyWireS](https://github.com/rambo/TinyWire/tree/master/TinyWireS)** and *TinyWireS.h* clearly has a public function **onRequest**. I opened the .ZIP file (downloaded from https://github.com/rambo/TinyWire) and drag-dropped TinyWireS folder into the Arduino libraries folder. This is how I install ALL libraries.

**I am using Arduino 1.0.6**

What am I doing wrong?

### ATTiny85-Slave Code:

```
#include "TinyWireS.h"                  // wrapper class for I2C slave routines
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR  0x26            // i2c slave address (38)

byte t=10;

void setup()
{ 
   TinyWireS.begin(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR);      // init I2C Slave mode
   TinyWireS.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop()
{
}

void requestEvent()
{  
   TinyWireS.send(t);
}
```

### Arduino Uno-Master Code:

```
 #include <Wire.h>
 #define I2C_SLAVE_ADDR  0x26            // i2c slave address (38)

 void setup() 
 {
     Wire.begin();
     Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 void loop() 
 {
      byte num;

     // read 1 byte, from address 0x26
     Wire.requestFrom(I2C_SLAVE_ADDR, 1);

     while(Wire.available()) {
          num = Wire.read();
     }
     
     Serial.print("num = ");
     Serial.println(num,DEC);
 }
```

Comment: How did you install the library?

Comment: I opened the .ZIP file (downloaded from https://github.com/rambo/TinyWire) and drag-dropped TinyWireS folder into the Arduino libraries folder. This is how I install ALL libraries.

Comment: you may need to include: TinyWireS_stop_check();
in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile your code "ATTiny85-Slave Code" without problems.

You can try to extract the contents of the ZIP archive (i.e. the library) directly to the directory where your sketch is stored. `#include "TinyWireS.h"` should then pick up that version.

You should also switch on verbose output for the compilation to have a look at the directory in which the code is compiled. Here you would find (at least in my older Arduino IDE version) copies of the included files. (`/tmp/build...` on Linux systems.) You can then make sure the proper version of the files is used.

You can also search your drives for other copies of `TinyWireS.h`.

Comment: Which version of Arduino IDE are you using? What board did you select?

Comment: I am using `Arduino IDE 1.0`. It compiles with any board selection... Note that I did not install the Tiny hardware specs, but did a small hack in `usiTwiSlace.c`, declaring all missing symbols as `int`s.